# how to block when windows service running on server to delete path line from fixapi config file?

Tags: streambase

I have a Quickfix app running with windows service on windows server.
When windows service start, it delete path line from config file.
How can I fix this problem?

Comment: [default]
ConnectionType=initiator
ResetOnLogon=Y
ResetSeqNumFlag=Y
StartTime=00:00:00
EndTime=00:00:00
FileStoreMaxCachedMsgs=0

[session]
BeginString=FIX.4.4
SenderCompID=localpc
TargetCompID=streambase
SocketConnectHost=10.14.64.1
SocketConnectPort=25007
HeartBtInt=30
FileLogPath=D:\WindowsServices\BOA.WindowsService.MobileInvestment.Streambase\logs
FileStorePath=D:\WindowsServices\BOA.WindowsService.MobileInvestment.Streambase\store
DataDictionary=D:\WindowsServices\BOA.WindowsService.MobileInvestment.Streambase/FIX44.xml

Comment: Kerem -- Can you clarify? You've tagged streambase but you are asking about a QuickFIX windows service? Is this actually a StreamBase server process running as a Windows Service using our FIX Adapter and the QuickFIX/J FIX engine in-process? If so, what version of StreamBase is in use? Is "config file" the QuickFIX engine config file? There's no setting named path in that file so please clarify exactly what you are doing and exactly what is happening? I suspect your problem is environmental so it's hard to help debug only with the information you've provided so far.